# How to active the second console to a FreeBSD guest running in bhyve?

Tags: freebsd, virtual-machine, tty, serial-console, uart

## Background

I'm running FreeBSD 12.1-RELEASE as a host for [bhyve](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?bhyve) virtual machines.

I have a FreeBSD 12.1-RELEASE guest running inside a VM. I would like to have two TTY-class devices configured for it.

According to the manual page, in order to start the VM with two TTY-class devices I have to start bhyve with command-line options similar to those: `-l com1,/dev/nmdm0B -l com2,/dev/nmdm1B`. Then I should be able to connect to the guest via those two [nullmodem terminals](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?nmdm) with `cu -l /dev/nmdm0A` and `cu -l /dev/nmdm1A`.

## Problem

The first command works as expected: `cu -l /dev/nmdm0A` shows me the main console of the guest.

The second command, however, attaches to the guest, but shows nothing. I would expect to show me a login prompt as if switched to another TTY.

*What am I missing?*

---

### Additional details

- The guest is a fresh installation of FreeBSD.
- The output of `dmesg | grep uart` on the guest is as follows:

  ```
  uart0: <16550 or compatible> port 0x3f8-0x3ff irq 4 flags 0x10 on acpi0
  uart0: console (115200,n,8,1)
  uart1: <16550 or compatible> port 0x2f8-0x2ff irq 3 on acpi0
  ```
- I've tried setting `hint.uart.1.flags` first to `0x10` and then to `0x80` (although this one is for kernel debuggers from what I understand from [uart(4)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?uart)) and rebooted after each change. It didn't work.

#### References

- https://bsdjhb.blogspot.com/2018/10/using-bhyve-for-freebsd-development.html
- https://gist.github.com/landonf/d00a15ede7d5ccb0e371

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to modify `/etc/ttys` on the guest. On amd64, it has the following defaults:

```
#
# $FreeBSD: head/sbin/init/ttys.amd64 338454 2018-09-04 15:48:13Z brd $
#   @(#)ttys    5.1 (Berkeley) 4/17/89
#
# This file specifies various information about terminals on the system.
# It is used by several different programs.  Common entries for the
# various columns include:
#
# name  The name of the terminal device.
#
# getty The program to start running on the terminal.  Typically a
#       getty program, as the name implies.  Other common entries
#       include none, when no getty is needed, and xdm, to start the
#       X Window System.
#
# type The initial terminal type for this port.  For hardwired
#      terminal lines, this will contain the type of terminal used.
#      For virtual consoles, the correct type is typically xterm.
#      Other common values include dialup for incoming modem ports, and
#      unknown when the terminal type cannot be predetermined.
#
# status Must be on or off.  If on, init will run the getty program on
#        the specified port.  If the word "secure" appears, this tty
#        allows root login.
#
# name  getty               type    status      comments
#
# If console is marked "insecure", then init will ask for the root password
# when going to single-user mode.
console none                unknown off secure
#
ttyv0   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"     xterm   onifexists secure
# Virtual terminals
ttyv1   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"     xterm   onifexists secure
ttyv2   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"     xterm   onifexists secure
ttyv3   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"     xterm   onifexists secure
ttyv4   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"     xterm   onifexists secure
ttyv5   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"     xterm   onifexists secure
ttyv6   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"     xterm   onifexists secure
ttyv7   "/usr/libexec/getty Pc"     xterm   onifexists secure
ttyv8   "/usr/local/bin/xdm -nodaemon"  xterm   off secure
# Serial terminals
# The 'dialup' keyword identifies dialin lines to login, fingerd etc.
ttyu0   "/usr/libexec/getty 3wire"  vt100   onifconsole secure
ttyu1   "/usr/libexec/getty 3wire"  vt100   onifconsole secure
ttyu2   "/usr/libexec/getty 3wire"  vt100   onifconsole secure
ttyu3   "/usr/libexec/getty 3wire"  vt100   onifconsole secure
# Dumb console
dcons   "/usr/libexec/getty std.9600"   vt100   off secure
```

As you can see, the status of every ttyu terminal device is set to `onifconsole secure` (the `secure` part is irrelevant here). It means that this those terminal devices are only turned on if they act as a console. In order to make it possible to access those devices from the host we just need to replace `onifconsole` with `onifexists`.

In my particular case, I had to replace the following line:

```
ttyu1   "/usr/libexec/getty 3wire"  vt100   onifconsole secure
```

with:

```
ttyu1   "/usr/libexec/getty 3wire"  vt100   ifexists secure
```

As a result, it is now possible to connect to the guest system using the second console:

```
# cu -l /dev/nmdm1A
Password:
Connected
 
 
FreeBSD/amd64 (testvm) (ttyu1)
 
login: root
Password:
Last login: Fri Jun 26 19:59:40 on ttyu1
FreeBSD 12.1-RELEASE r354233 GENERIC
 
Welcome to FreeBSD!
```